# How to configure external authentication schemes after service startup

Tags: identityserver4

I want to roll my own instance of identityserver4 as authentication instance for a service I am hosting in the cloud.

My concrete scenario is that I want to be able for customers to set up using their ADFS in a self service manner similar to how slack, expensify or namely allow this.

I know how federating works. Usually in the Startup in ConfigureServices you add the following

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie("cookie")
                .AddSaml2p("idp1", options => {
                  .....
                .AddSaml2p("idp3", options => {
```

and so on and I can use the same of the scheme to later challenge the external ADFS. But this is only and always happening at the startup of the service. When a customer is configuring the connection to his ADFS later my service is already up and running and I don't want to restart my service to be able to configure the federation between my identityserver and the external provider.

Is there a way to configure this without restarting the service?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 options as I see it:

- https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/dynamic-authentication-providers
- *OR* - as I had to a couple of years ago before anything like the above existed - creating your own version of the authentication handler (surprisingly few changes required) to accept parameters via the properties passed to `ChallengeAsync()`. In the case of OIDC all I needed to override was the authority URL and client ID since it's I'm only using `id_token`.